# adding google ads to android app

Tags: android, ads

i am tying to add google ads to my app(this is my 1st time). i have added the jar file also.

Here is the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/headerbgcolor"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="@string/back" 
            android:onClick="finishActivity"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headertitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/header_title" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="@string/home" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a14f26e5d930307"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="AVD_for_4in_WVGA_Nexus_S,5554" />



    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but i am not able to define adview in my class, when i am trying to define it in the class.

here is my class where i am tryin to define.

```
public class Cities extends Activity {

    Button btnback = null;
    Button btnhome = null;
    TextView headertitle = null;
    ListView lstcities;
    ImageView imgfooter;
    AdView adView; 
    public String BtnSelected;
```

i am getting error Adview cannot be resolved to type, when i'm trying to define

```
AdView adview;
```

what is the poblem?

Comment: checked your imports ?

Comment: @njzk2 i am using eclipse. it automatically imports the required packages. but i am not able to import the google.ads packages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used this jar file - **GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.0.4.jar**

have you imported this lines

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;


        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,
                    getString(R.string.publisherID));


        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imgBanner);
        layout.addView(adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.setTesting(true);
        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

In XML I have just written this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/imgBanner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

ANd in Manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode" >
</activity>
```

Comment: i am not able to import those classes. i tried before posting the question also

Comment: i just downloaded from google. i didnt get which version it is

Comment: you have added jar file - what is name of jar file? ANd after adding jar file to libs folder, have you Refrence Libraries?

Comment: it was just GoogleAdMobAdsSdk. thnx for your suggestion i changed it to GoogleAdMobAdsSdk4.0.2. now i am able to import the packages. now when i run my app it's just displaying empty space in the space where i want to display the google ads. what might be the problem

Comment: I think you have to keep testing mode as ON

Comment: whr to keep testing mode as ON?. could u pls help me.

Comment: See i have edited my answer - add this line adRequest.setTesting(true);

Comment: i added settesting(true). but still ads r not displaying

Comment: sry yar. i tried to vote the answer. but i dont have 15 reputation to vote it says.

Comment: Its ok. Have you changed this publisherID to your ID