# adding google ads to android app not display ads

Tags: android, admob

Working on displaying google ads in android app by using stackoverflow 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404682/adding-google-ads-to-android-app/15404909#15404909)

After following instructions it shows ad view but ad not display and on ad view a message appears - `you must have AdAcitvity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with config changes`. 
I have allready added activity in manifest,i am surprising why this occure. Please help me in my problem and give your suggestion .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your current manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://manijshrestha.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/integrating-admob-in-your-android-app-and-make-money/) is very Good Example of admob integration into android app.

Your problem is nothing just put into **manifest** file.

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Comment: please check answer and give response.Happy coding

Comment: Thanks sir, Its working for me..Previously i was using in manifest -<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode" ></activity> but it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

The question in the link is a bit old. You should make a few changes:

Use the latest version of AdMob. The latest version is 6.4.1 and you can find it [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadandroid).

Your manifest should have more config changes declared like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Check all the instructions in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/?hl=en_GB#android).

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
1. download latest google-play-services,jar
2. add jar to project build path

**main.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/lnrMain">

</LinearLayout>

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    LinearLayout lnrMain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lnrMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrMain);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AdView adView = new AdView(MyActivity.this);
                adView.setAdUnitId("0445b7141d9d4e1b");
                adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
                AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
                adView.loadAd(builder.build());
                lnrMain.addView(adView);
            }
        });

    }
}

**AndroidManifest.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.Demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4030500" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```